# Services module retrieve node with PHP text format

Tags: nodes, services

I have successfully connected to a Drupal instance using JSON and even retrieved a node using the service.

Problem is that the node has php content type, and the service returns the raw php content instead of the eventual value.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a work-around to this?

Comment: Sounds like you need PHP on your web server, you get raw PHP code if there's no PHP interpreter on your webserver.

Comment: Hi beebee sorry but seems like I cannot respond to your comment. On a browser, the page displays as expected. Not php code but the actual value

Comment: Don't use PHP text formatter to begin with, that is bad/horrible practice. Do your php logic in a node preprocess function or in a hook.

Comment: Oh you're storing PHP code in your content/database? If you want that code processed you need to do it on your PHP server I think... Otherwise the PHP code will just get returned as a text content.